# how to shade points in scatter based on colormap in matplotlib?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I'm trying to shade points in a scatter plot based on a set of values (from 0 to 1) picked from one of the already defined color maps, like Blues or Reds. I tried this:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import *
from scipy import *
fig = plt.figure()
mymap = plt.get_cmap("Reds")
x = [8.4808517662594909, 11.749082788323497, 5.9075039082855652, 3.6156231827873615, 12.536817102137768, 11.749082788323497, 5.9075039082855652, 3.6156231827873615, 12.536817102137768]
spaced_colors = linspace(0, 1, 10)
print spaced_colors
plt.scatter(x, x,
            color=spaced_colors,
            cmap=mymap)
# this does not work either
plt.scatter(x, x,
            color=spaced_colors,
            cmap=plt.get_cmap("gray"))
```

But it does not work, using either the Reds or gray color map. How can this be done?

*edit*: if I want to plot each point separately so it can have a separate legend, how can I do it? I tried:

```
fig = plt.figure()
mymap = plt.get_cmap("Reds")
data = np.random.random([10, 2])
colors = list(linspace(0.1, 1, 5)) + list(linspace(0.1, 1, 5))
print "colors: ", colors
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.scatter(data[:, 0], data[:, 1],
           c=colors,
           cmap=mymap)
plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
# attempt to plot first five points in five shades of red,
# with a separate legend for each point
for n in range(5):
    plt.scatter([data[n, 0]], [data[n, 1]],
               c=[colors[n]],
               cmap=mymap,
               label="point %d" %(n))
plt.legend()
```

but it fails. I need to make a call to scatter for each point so that it can have a separate label=, but still want each point to have a different shade of the color map as its color.
thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you really want to do this (what you describe in your edit), you have to "pull" the colors from your colormap (I have commented all changes I made to your code):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

# plt.subplots instead of plt.subplot
# create a figure and two subplots side by side, they share the
# x and the y-axis
fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=2, sharey=True, sharex=True)
data = np.random.random([10, 2]) 
# np.r_ instead of lists
colors = np.r_[np.linspace(0.1, 1, 5), np.linspace(0.1, 1, 5)] 
mymap = plt.get_cmap("Reds")
# get the colors from the color map
my_colors = mymap(colors)
# here you give floats as color to scatter and a color map
# scatter "translates" this
axes[0].scatter(data[:, 0], data[:, 1], s=40,
                c=colors, edgecolors='None',
                cmap=mymap)
for n in range(5):
    # here you give a color to scatter
    axes[1].scatter(data[n, 0], data[n, 1], s=40,
                    color=my_colors[n], edgecolors='None',
                    label="point %d" %(n))
# by default legend would show multiple scatterpoints (as you would normally
# plot multiple points with scatter)
# I reduce the number to one here
plt.legend(scatterpoints=1)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: colored-scatter]

However, if you only want to plot 10 values and want to name every single one,
you should consider using something different, for instance a bar chart as in this
[example](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/barh_demo.html). Another opportunity would be to use `plt.plot` with a custom color cycle, like in this [example](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/api/color_cycle.html).

Answer (score 13):

[As per the documentation](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.scatter), you want the `c` keyword argument instead of `color`. (I agree that this is a bit confusing, but the "c" and "s" terminology is inherited from matlab, in this case.)

E.g.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

x, y, colors = np.random.random((3,10))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x, y, c=colors, s=50, cmap=mpl.cm.Reds)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: It's worthwhile mentioning one quirk: if you start with the OP's code and change `color` to `c`, it still won't work, because `x` only has 9 elements while `spaced_colors` has 10, which triggers a different branch in `scatter`.  Changing it to `spaced_colors = linspace(0, 1, len(x))` (or anything else) fixes this.

Comment: why doesn't it work if you specify the color of each point individually by multiple calls to `scatter`?

Comment: Because there is a step inside scatter which defines a normalization instance, and because it doesn't have context of all the data, the normalization cannot scale the dataset correctly (and hence gets the wrong colors). My answer might give some more clues as to how to use cmaps and norms.

Answer (score 7):

How about:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


reds = plt.get_cmap("Reds")
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 10)
y = np.log(x)

# color by value given a cmap
plt.subplot(121)
plt.scatter(x, y, c=x, s=100, cmap=reds)


# color by value, and add a legend for each
plt.subplot(122)
norm = plt.normalize()
norm.autoscale(x)
for i, (x_val, y_val) in enumerate(zip(x, y)):
    plt.plot(x_val, y_val, 'o', markersize=10, 
             color=reds(norm(x_val)),
             label='Point %s' % i
             )
plt.legend(numpoints=1, loc='lower right')

plt.show()
```

[image: code output]

The code should all be fairly self explanatory, but if you want me to go over anything, just shout.