# Add Color To 3D Scatter Plot

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, colors

I have a list of x,y,z points and a list of values assigned to each 3D point.
Now the question is, how can I color each point in a 3D scatter plot according to the list of values ?

The colors should be typical engineering -> RGB -> lowest blue to highest red

Thanks a lot

Basically I am searching for an equivalent to: scatter3(X,Y,Z,S,C)
See here: https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter3.html

I tried:

```
col = [i/max(values)*255 for i in values]


ax.scatter(sequence_containing_x_vals, sequence_containing_y_vals, sequence_containing_z_vals,c=col, marker='o')
pyplot.show()
```

..but I don't get the desired result

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to shade points in scatter based on colormap in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11885060/how-to-shade-points-in-scatter-based-on-colormap-in-matplotlib)

Comment: Just try to extend the solution in the duplicate to your 3d case. For more help, it would be nice to provide a minimal working example which reproduces your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the recommended way of producing scatters with colors is to supply the values directly to `c`:

```
ax.scatter(x, y, z, c=values, marker='o', cmap="Spectral")
```

Minimal example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

x = y = z = values = [1,2,3,4,5]

ax = plt.subplot(projection="3d")
sc = ax.scatter(x, y, z, c=values, marker='o', s=100, cmap="Spectral")

plt.colorbar(sc)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I see, but what if the z-position does not reflect the actual value. You can think of heat spread in a room. It will be warmer next to the heaters, which are not necessarily located at the ceiling. How would you change the color accordingly then ?

Comment: To make this example short, I used the same list for all 4 dimensions. In a real case you will have 4 different lists or arrays.